# Postgres / SQL Databases: How to enforce unique combination of key/value Pairs

Tags: sql, postgresql

a new Project requires a dynamic datamodel, meaning that the Properties for a record are stored in a seperate table like this:

```
Items:
ID | insertiondate
 1 | 2017-01-31


Properties:
ID | fk_Item_ID |     Key      |     Value
 1 |     1      |  referenceNr |       1
 2 |     1      |    office    |       O1
```

...

What i need now is a possibility to enforce that a "referenceNumber" in unique per "office".

so the insertion into this table with the 2 values (1, O2) is ok as well as (2, O1) - but (1, O1) has to violate the Constraint.

Is there a simple way to handle this?

Comment: Should the referencenumber be unique per item (and office) or for all all items with the same office

Comment: an Item can only have one occurence of each, but this is easily done by unique(fk_Item_ID, Key)

Comment: short: office "O1" can only have one referenceNr: "1". this each item has 0-1 refNr and 0-1 office - there can never be two items with the same combination of referenceNr+office

Comment: Does it make any sense to have two distinct rows in `Properties` for the same `fk_Item_ID`? If not, just use a unique constraint on `(fk_Item_ID, Key)`. If it does for *some* keys, but not for `referenceNr` and `office`, you could use multiple, partial unique indexes.

Answer (score 1):

Even if the project really asks for some key/value entries, this doesn't seem to be true for `referencenr` and `office` as you want to apply constraints on the pair. So simply put the two in your items table and add the constraint.

The only other option I see is to make the two one entry:

```
ID | fk_Item_ID | Key                  | Value
 1 |     1      | 'referenceNr/office' | '1/01'
```

I'd go for the first solution. Have key/value pairs only where absolutely necessary (and where the DBMS may be oblivious as to their content and mutual relations).

Comment: Say the use case is: today the customer says "office+refNr are to be unique", tomorrow they say "the have to be unique except if a third property we just invented eg. 'archived' is set to <true> for the item" and the next day they say "we do not want to have office saved at all and referenceNr needs to be unique on its own" and the changing the structure of Tables is a slow process here

Comment: goal is to be able to add and drop keys form an item's properties without the need to alter any tables or eg. Hibernate Entities

Comment: With such volatile rules as you describe, you cannot install a constraint in the database. You would rather build a rule engine and apply the rules yourself. I.e. write a function (in PL/pgSQL) to insert/update data into/in the table. In this function look up your rules, see that the combination of `referencenr` and `office` must be uniue in the table, scan the table to see whether an entry for the pair exists, if yes throw an error, if not perform the insert. That is certainly a lot of work. Good luck.

Comment: i moved this logic to a rule engine, as you said. in fact this IS business logic after all